# How to save twitter feed entries to a django model?

Tags: xml, django-models, twitter

So, here is a twitter feed that I want to save to a model: [#stackoverflow](http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=stackoverflow). I am able to get each entry in the feed as a dictionary using [feedparser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/). And the data looks like this:

```
{ 'author': u'stackfeed (StackOverflow)',
  'author_detail': { 'href': u'http://twitter.com/stackfeed',
                     'name': u'stackfeed (StackOverflow)'},
  'authors': [ { 'href': u'http://twitter.com/stackfeed',
                 'name': u'stackfeed (StackOverflow)'}],
  'content': [ { 'base': u'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=stackoverflow',
                 'language': u'en-US',
                 'type': u'text/html',
                 'value': u'How to inject a single factory instance to multiple repositories and unit of work using ninject?: First, I have ... <a href="http://t.co/vYqLsWj5">http://t.co/vYqLsWj5</a>'}],
  'guidislink': True,
  'href': u'http://twitter.com/stackfeed',
  'id': u'tag:search.twitter.com,2005:164382321993187328',
  'link': u'http://twitter.com/stackfeed/statuses/164382321993187328',
  'links': [ { 'href': u'http://twitter.com/stackfeed/statuses/164382321993187328',
               'rel': u'alternate',
               'type': u'text/html'},
             { 'href': u'http://a2.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png',
               'rel': u'image',
               'type': u'image/png'}],
  'published': u'2012-01-31T16:19:34Z',
  'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=16, tm_min=19, tm_sec=34, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0),
  'summary': u'How to inject a single factory instance to multiple repositories and unit of work using ninject?: First, I have ... <a href="http://t.co/vYqLsWj5">http://t.co/vYqLsWj5</a>',
  'title': u'How to inject a single factory instance to multiple repositories and unit of work using ninject?: First, I have ... http://t.co/vYqLsWj5',
  'title_detail': { 'base': u'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=stackoverflow',
                    'language': u'en-US',
                    'type': u'text/plain',
                    'value': u'How to inject a single factory instance to multiple repositories and unit of work using ninject?: First, I have ... http://t.co/vYqLsWj5'},
  u'twitter_geo': u'',
  u'twitter_lang': u'en',
  u'twitter_metadata': u'',
  u'twitter_result_type': u'recent',
  u'twitter_source': u'<a href="http://twitterfeed.com" rel="nofollow">twitterfeed</a>',
  'updated': u'2012-01-31T16:19:34Z',
  'updated_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=16, tm_min=19, tm_sec=34, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=31, tm_isdst=0)}
```

And I want to save all this information into a model. How should I construct my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...
    uri = models. ...

class Tweet(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author'), related_name='tweets')
    title
    content = models.TextField
    published_datetime
    summary
```

and add more fields as needed.

Comment: THanks for the reply. Don't you think it will be a problem if twitter decides to change one of the fields, or add or remove a couple fields in the future?

Comment: @archmage if twitter changes the fields you will have to change your parser anyway.

Comment: why do you think so? i'm just getting the feed and dumping it to the database. even if I have to change a couple of things here and there, it would be of great help if I didn't have to change the model.

Comment: Are you getting the feed as an xml or json? I think either way you should perform a validation on every single field before you map it to the correct field in your models. It does not necessary mean you have to change your models, unless you are interested in the newly added fields in the feed.

Comment: I'm getting the data as XML. And I am looking for a way to store a tree data into the model, regardless of the field names or tree depth. Something like nested parent-child relationship model. I am not interested in the newly added fields right now, but I may be in the future.

Comment: I don't actually think this is a good idea but you could build a generic tree model something like class Node(models.Model): that has a foreign key to itself and hold two attributes prop_name and prop_value.